# inflate options list after clicking a button

Tags: android

I would like to inflate an option list like this one after clicking on a certain button.

[image]

I didn't like to call it option menu because I'm not pressing the "menu" button.
I want the items to be listed like the one above..

Is it possible to use the same .xml file used to create an option menu inflater for my case?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    
        <item
            android:id="@+id/first_menu_item"
            android:title="First Menu Item">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/second_menu_item"
            android:title="Second Menu Item">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/third_menu_item"
            android:title="Third Menu Item">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/fourth_menu_item"
            android:title="Fourth Menu Item">
        </item>

</menu>
```

I hope some experts can help me achieve what I really want to do.

Comment: "I didn't like to call it option menu because I'm not pressing the 'menu' button." Do you want to use a ContextMenu?

Comment: yes i think it's called ContextMenu.. Thank you for clarifying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`ContextMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html).

Activities and Fragments have the `registerForContextMenu()` and `onCreateContextMenu()` to quickly implement one of these.  If you ever want to open a ContextMenu with a regular OnClickListener (rather than waiting for a long click event) you can use [`openContextMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29) directly.
See the Developer's Guide on [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) for detailed information and example code.

And if you are using API 11+ you can use a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) instead, this is describeed in the Menu guide as well.

Comment: Thank you, i succeeded to make it work with ContextMenu. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

That's a popup menu, which is documented in the API guide.

However, depending on what you're trying to do, it may not be consistent with Android design guidelines. I encourage you to follow the guidelines whenever possible, because this will make your app easier to use. As users see more and more UI consistency across apps, Android itself becomes easier to use.